# Django crispy forms only partially loading css

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to create a crispy form that looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV4Qy.png), but my code renders a default html input box and a disjoint bootstrap button instead of the desired, "connected" form. My form code looks something like:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField()    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['query'].label = ""
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            FieldWithButtons('query', StrictButton(">>", type="submit", css_class="btn-success"), css_class='input-xlarge')
        )
        self.helper.form_tag = False
```

It creates something that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EZzl.png). How do I fix this?

Comment: The problem's unlikely to be in your Django form code. Are your CSS files being included in the generated header? Can you post a live example rather than an image screenshot?

Comment: I included bootstrap.min.css in my HTML base code (and it shows up in the generated header), which is all I should need for this to work according to the docs. What exactly do you mean by a live example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want Bootstrap. Try setting `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap'` (or `bootstrap3`) in your `settings.py`, as per [this documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#setting-media-files).

Comment: Wow, changing it from 'bootstrap' to 'bootstrap3' fixed it! Thank you! On a side note, how would I prevent the search bar from taking up the entire page (but still make it take up a good amount)?

Comment: No problem. Remember to accept the answer if this helped you. As for your search bar, that's a different question -- read up on Bootstrap's grid layout and, if that still doesn't make sense, feel free to ask me again and I'll pull you into a chat.

Comment: Would you be able to pull me into a chat to help me out a bit? I thought I would be able to modify the form size using css_class="input-medium" or something similar, but this appears to not work in bootstrap3 and I'm not sure how to fix it in the actual form code